# FB - Problem with getting "manage_page" permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

I'm using the following to get "manage_page" permission.

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_SITE_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token

But when I goto this link, it was successful and redirected to MY_SITE_LINK. But when tested on another FB user, it gives an error saying:

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>   We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

What happened ?

Answer (score 0):

My_site_url is canvas URL? Like http://apps.facebook.com/…